# ESP32 reading analog 2.4Ghz

Tags: wifi, esp32, analogread, analog

Is there a possibility to analog read on the 2.4Ghz band to just read how much activity is in the presence of your device? Not parsing the messages but just listening to how strong of a signal you are getting on a specific bandwidth?

All information is welcome.